# How to parse JSON file that is being worked on

Tags: json, file, go, unmarshalling

I have a file with JSON in this format:

```
[{
    "id": "1055972353245622272",
    "lang": "und",
    "date": "Sat Oct 27 00:00:02 +0000 2018",
    "text": "#BTC 6474 346 0 08 #ETH 203 317 0 13 #XRP 0 459 0 04 #BCH 438 922 0 0 #EOS 5 388 0 12 #XLM 0 235 0 41 #LTC 52 106 0 03 #ADA 0 074 0 17 #USDT 0 99 0 07 #XMR 105 022 0 13 #TRX 0 024 0 21 "
},
{
    "id": "1055972355506401280",
    "lang": "en",
    "date": "Sat Oct 27 00:00:03 +0000 2018",
    "text": "Don t want to miss any of our public #crypto trading #signals Want instant updates of our premium channel #performance Searching for #crypto news Get instantly notified on our public telegram channel Join now at https t co akfmLiArya #DGB #SC #MFT #EOS #XVG #BTC #TRX https t co HT2RAOIjfh"
},
```

This file is being worked on by **program1** in random intervals (when a tweet that match filter is found). I want to read this file by **program2** - in 5 minutes timesteps.
But I am unable to.

The unmarshaling (`json.Unmarshal(file, &data)`) is not allowing me to read it - as it throws an error as JSON is not correct.

I do not want to redesign the architecture with the usage of DB, I want to be able to operate on files as intended.

How can I access the files and have them parsed as JSON?

Workaround with reading the file and closing the JSON

```
file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
closingJson := "{}]"
file = append(file, closingJson...)
json.Unmarshal(file, &data)
```

Comment: The file contents isn't legal JSON. You probably need to read it, fix it, then parse it.

Comment: That was my guess as well - currently in testing - but I was hoping that someone smarter can find a way with https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode or some other trick I am not familiar with.

Comment: also your `date` cannot be mapped to `time.Time`

Comment: Fix program1 so it doesn't write invalid/incomplete JSON to the file. Write to a temporary file in the same filesystem as the real file, then rename the temporary file. That's an atomic operation and program2 will never observe partially written data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to treat it as a [JSON stream](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder_Decode_stream):

https://play.golang.org/p/6drcizYKrrJ

```
    type Message struct {
      Id   string `json:"id"`
      Lang string `json:"lang"`
      Date string `json:"date"`
      Text string `json:"text"`
    }

    jsonStream, err := os.Open(`/tmp/json`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dec := json.NewDecoder(jsonStream)

    // read open bracket
    _, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // while the array contains values
    for dec.More() {
      var m Message
      // decode an array value (Message)
      err := dec.Decode(&m)
      if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v : %v : %v : %v\n", m.Id, m.Lang, m.Date, m.Text)
      } else {
        // wait for more contents - sleep?  use a channel and wait to be notified?
      }

    }
```